# Retrieve multiple Latitude Longitude from firebase Database

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I want to retrieve multiple LatLng from firebase through single on-click actually I am fetching single LatLng from firebase.how can I fetch plz tell me
Here is Map-activity code

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Location");

    ValueEventListener listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Double latitude=dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            Double longitude=dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

            // Add a marker in Lahore and move the camera
          //  LatLng Lahore = new LatLng(31.588048, 74.315097);
            //Different Map types
            //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Shahi Qila"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,15.2f));
           // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Lahore));
            //zoom
    /*
    CameraUpdate zoom= CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20);
    mMap.moveCamera(zoom);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);*/

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and here is database structure

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix7Is.png)

Comment: Hey @HamzaChohan, Can you please add your database structure?

Comment: sorry for the late reply I have added the structure of the database plz help ASAP

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok, but you must check data that received in

> onDataChange

with debug point.

and say what happen when you run app
update me in comments

Comment: sorry for the late reply I have added the structure of the database plz HELP ASAP

Answer (score 0):

First create **Model** to parse data directly

```
public class MyLocation {
    String des;
    double latitude, longitude;

    public String getDes() {
        return des;
    }

    public void setDes(String des) {
        this.des = des;
    }

    public Long getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Long latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Long getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Long longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Then query on `DatabaseReference` like below to get data

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ValueEventListener listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot locationSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            MyLocation myLocation = locationSnapshot.getValue(MyLocation.class);

            LatLng location = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Shahi Qila"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15.2f));
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Hey @HamzaChohan, did you try this?